# Numpy seterr for all functions in module

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling

I have a module containing functions with numpy operations. I would like to raise an exception for any floating-point error (e.g., division by zero) that occurs in any of the functions.

This line of code causes all floating-point errors to be raised:

```
np.seterr(all='raise')
```

I'm wondering how to set this for all functions in the module, without it affecting code outside of the module.

As I understand it, writing the line under `if __name__ == '__main__':` won't help, because it won't be invoked when the module is imported.

Is there a better way than writing `np.seterr(all='raise')` inside each function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility could be:

```
# only list functions that need to be exported
__all__ = ['main', 'foo', 'bar', 'division',]


def main():
    np.seterr(all='raise')
    # ....
    # further function calls


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Here is a concrete example:

Create a module for e.g. `sample.py`

```
import numpy as np

__all__ = ['main', 'foo', 'bar', 'division',]

def foo():
    print('this is function foo')

def bar():
    print('this is function bar')

def division():
    print("division by zero might occur here...")

def main():
    np.seterr(all='raise')
    print('this is the main function')

# only executed when run from the commandline as: python sample.py
if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    main()
```

Then import this module in for e.g. an `ipython` prompt or from some other module:

```
In [1]: import sample

# only the functions included in `__all__` will be imported
In [2]: sample.__all__
Out[2]: ['main', 'foo', 'bar', 'division']

# call whichever function is needed
In [3]: sample.main()
this is the main function
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `main()` function not be run when the module is imported, since it's called under `if __name__ == "__main__"`?

Comment: @Vermillion added an example!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the thread is alive for quite long, and I guess you/others already managed, but for future viewers (like me), here's something to save a few minutes of your life:

```
import numpy as np


def unmasked_call(func):
    def func2(*args, **kwargs):
        with np.errstate(all='raise'):
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return func2


@unmasked_call
def one():
    print ("One:")
    return np.max([1, 2, np.nan])


print ("Starting")
one()
```